# Android Alert Dialog still attached to Context after click outside

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi I have a strange Problem.
I have an Activity with a Fragment with a RecyclerView. When a user clicks on an item I show a simple alert dialog where the user can make some specifications. When the user has selected something within the dialog, I close the dialog and finish the activity to go back to the parent activity.
This works as expected but if the user selects nothing and closes the dialog with a click outside and goes back to the parent activity, leakcanary shows me that the dialog is still attached to the activity context. So my question is how to avoid that?
I have already tried to set an onCancel or an onDismissListener to dismiss the dialog myself but that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a destroy where method where I dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

This might work.